# Reading a File without line breaks using Buffered reader

Tags: java, performance, file, bufferedreader

I am reading a file with comma separated values which when split into an array will have 10 values for each line . I expected the file to have line breaks so that

```
line = bReader.readLine()
```

will give me each line. But my file doesnt have a line break. Instead after the first set of values there are lots of spaces(465 to be precise) and then the next line begins.

So my above code of readLine() is reading the entire file in one go as there are no lined breaks. Please suggest how best to efficiently tackle this scenario.

Comment: Can it be a file with fixed sized records? Maybe of 512 bytes or such. Then one could repeatedly read a fixed sized byte buffer.

Comment: There are 11 values in each line separated by commas. followed by 465 space characters. Then next set of comma separated values. But the number of characters in each line might vary whereas it will always be 11 values (10 commas).  The file size also might vary.

Comment: What do you mean by 'efficiently'? In the sense of minimal code or performance of the operation? The latter should be good, as BufferedReader will load the file into memory efficiently. 
If you have very large files which you do not want to handle in memory, then an efficient way would be to read smaller parts into a buffer, say a few kB at a time.

Comment: By efficiently i meant performance wise and also i am not clear of how to solve this. Like should i replace the 465 space chars with "\n" and then read by line? Reading by 512 bytes will read my first line? Sorry that i am not able to grasp but a code sample would help

Answer (score 1):

One way is to replace String with 465 spaces in your text with new line character "\n" before iterating it for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I second Ninan's answer: replace the 465 spaces with a newline, then run the function you were planning on running earlier.

For aesthetics and readability I would suggest using Regex's Pattern to  replace the spaces instead of a long unreadable `String.replace("                         ")`.

Your code could like below, but replace 6 with 465:

```
 // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String content = "DOG,CAT      MOUSE,CHEESE";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[ ]{6}",
            Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String newString = p.matcher(content).replaceAll("\n");
    System.out.println(newString); 
  }
```

Comment: Yes this will solve my second part of problem which implies that i have to read the entire file into a single string and then do the above process. but the first part is that sometimes it is a very large file and reading the entire file into a single line is causing some memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is read file f1.txt and write to anther file f2.txt  by removing all empty lines and spaces then read f2.txt something like

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("f1.txt"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("f2.txt"); 
String line;

 while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{ 
line = line.trim(); // remove leading and trailing whitespace
if (!line.equals("")) // don't write out blank lines
{
    fw.write(line, 0, line.length());
}
```

}

Then try using your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might create your own subclass of a `FilterInputStream` or a `PushbackInputStream` and pass that to an `InputStreamReader`. One overrides `int read()`.

Such a class unfortunately needs a bit of typing. (A nice excercise so to say.)

```
private static final int NO_CHAR = -2;
private boolean fromCache;
private int cachedSpaces;
private int cachedNonSpaceChar = NO_CHAR;

int read() throws IOException {
    if (fromCache) {
        if (cachecSpaces > 0) ...
        if (cachedNonSpaceChar != NO_CHAR) ...
        ...
    }
    int ch = super.read();
    if (ch != -1) {
        ...
    }
    return ch;
}
```

The idea is to cache spaces till either a nonspace char, and in `read()` either take from the cache, return `\n` instead, call `super.read()` when not from cache, recursive `read` when space.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have a flat CSV file without proper line break, which supposed to have 10 values on each line.

Updated:
1. (Recommended) You can use Scanner class with useDelimiter to parse csv effectively, assuming you are trying to store 10 values from a line:

```
    public static void parseCsvWithScanner() throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.csv"));

    // set your delimiter for scanner, "," for csv
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");

    // storing 10 values as a "line"
    int LINE_LIMIT = 10;

    // implement your own data structure to store each value of CSV
    int[] tempLineArray = new int[LINE_LIMIT];

    int lineBreakCount = 0;

    while(scanner.hasNext()) {

        // trim start and end spaces if there is any
        String temp = scanner.next().trim();
        tempLineArray[lineBreakCount++] = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        if (lineBreakCount == LINE_LIMIT) {

            // replace your own logic for handling the full array
            for(int i=0; i<tempLineArray.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(tempLineArray[i]);
            } // end replace

            // resetting array and counter
            tempLineArray = new int[LINE_LIMIT];
            lineBreakCount = 0;
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

2. Or use the BufferedReader.
   You might not need the ArrayList to store all values if there is memory issue by replacing your own logic.

   ```
   public static void parseCsv() throws IOException {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
       // your delimiter
       char TOKEN = ',';
       // your requirement of storing 10 values for each "line"
       int LINE_LIMIT = 10;
       // tmp for storing from BufferedReader.read()
       int tmp;
       // a counter for line break
       int lineBreakCount = 0;
       // array for storing 10 values, assuming the values of CSV are integers
       int[] tempArray = new int[LINE_LIMIT];
       // storing tempArray of each line to ArrayList
       ArrayList<int[]> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       while((tmp = br.read()) != -1) {
           if ((char)tmp == TOKEN) {
               if (lineBreakCount == LINE_LIMIT) {
                   // your logic to handle the current "line" here.
                   lineList.add(tempArray);
                   // new "line"
                   tempArray = new int[LINE_LIMIT];
                   lineBreakCount = 0;
               }
               // storing current value from buffer with trim of spaces
               tempArray[lineBreakCount] =
                       Integer.parseInt(sb.toString().trim());
               lineBreakCount++;
               // clear the buffer
               sb.delete(0, sb.length());
           }
           else {
               // add current char from BufferedReader if not delimiter
               sb.append((char)tmp);
           }
       }
       br.close();
   }
   ```